# Is there a limit to the number of test friend requests that can be sent by a sandboxed Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

Been tweaking my app's invite process and sending invites to two test accounts. They've worked fine.

In the last few days, my friend requests are not being sent out to the test users. Is there a finite number of times this can be used in a sandboxed app?

I set up another test app and a request went through okay.

Answer (score 0):

In [fb docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20120507131750/http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/) it says something about limits for invites, but it doesn't say whether or not it is true for the sandbox mode.

> A user may invite a number of people each day equal to the maximum number of requests allocated to your application. If a user attempts to go over this limit, the following message appears:
>   [image]
>   <sub>(source: [marketworks.com](http://images.marketworks.com/hi/1/1088/pp_too_many.jpg))</sub>

Some interesting discussion is going on in [this thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=30560&p=2), looks like invite feature could be suspended if they detect fake users.

Comment: Hmm, haven't seen the "Sorry" popup, the test users just don't receive the invite. And these aren't fake users, but Facebook-sanctioned test users: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Test_Accounts